# Randomness and Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose the probability of a "random" event is very small (call this probability $p$). In real life, true randomness seems impossible. So would the actual true probability of the event be greater than $p$?

Comment: This seems akin to a longstanding joke in which one person says "Suppose that there are $s$ sheep" and somebody asks "But what if the number of sheep is different?". If you denote some probability $p$, that is your notation: no more. Clearly what its magnitude is numerically and whether you can estimate it accurately are key questions; in abstraction all we can say is that some probabilities are more difficult to estimate than others. That can be said independently of any speculation about "true randomness".

Comment: It might be worth expanding on what you mean by "true randomness seems impossible." Or more generally, give a concrete example of what you're trying to describe/ask.

Answer (score 2):

When you flip a coin, you cannot know if it will fall on heads or tails.
There is a chance in will fall of heads and a chance it will fall on tails, both being a half. This seems like true randomness. The theory of probability has the purpose of stamping on events a certain probability.

Logically, your question makes no sense. You assume that something has a probability, and then ask if its probability is greater. You assume, for instance, that the odds of flipping a heads is 0.2, then you say there is no randomness, and conclude that the odds of flipping a heads is 0.4...

Comment: That is exactly how I understand the question. It just doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your question raises the philosophical question of whether or not randomness is possible - while it's an interesting subject, we pretty genuinely don't care.

We do care, however, about your particular interpretation of probability, which is the important part (though they both agree that the answer to your question is "No, the probability is $p$", based on their individual criteria). Briefly consider the two prevailing interpretations:

1. A [Frequentist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability) would say that the given probability $p$ is the fraction of times that the event occurs in a very large number of trials. In this case, the number $p$ arises as a result of a large number of empirical trials; it is our best estimate based on the experimental evidence at hand.
2. A [Bayesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) would say that based on some sufficient evidence, we have calculated the number $p$ to express how sure we are of the outcome of the event. Note that we need not to have seen a large number of trials or any trials at all; this is a direct epistemological claim about our sureness in the outcome of the event.

Both views agree that we could be wrong; however, $p$ is still the best bet we have. So in a way it is true that under both interpretations $p$ *could* be incorrect; however, it is not particularly helpful to say so and undermines the usefulness of using $p$ in the first place.